# Calling SQL Stored procedure using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have following SQL Stored Procedure

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextNumberTest]
@NEWNUMBER varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @NEWNUMBER = 'ABC00001'
    RETURN 1
END
```

I am trying to read NENUMBER value using dapper, here is my code

```
private string GetNextNumber()
{
    var dynamicParams = new DynamicParameters();
    dynamicParams.Add("rval", DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    dynamicParams.Add("NEWNUMBER", DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    var data = db.QueryMultiple("GetNextNumberTest", dynamicParams, commandType:    CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    var result = dynamicParams.Get<string>("NEWNUMBER");
    return result;
}
```

But i always get the following error

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Dapper.dll but was    not handled in user code

Additional information: Error converting data type varchar to int.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple usage errors:

1. passing `DbType.Int32` / `DbType.String` as the *value* rather than the *data type*
2. if you aren't passing a string value, it needs a hint for the length
3. you should use `Execute`, not `QueryMultiple` here
4. using the return of `Execute` to mean the return value of the stored procedure (that simply isn't how ADO.NET works; the return value there is theoretically the rows affected, but it is usually a meaningless number)

So:

```
dynamicParams.Add("rval", dbType: DbType.Int32,
    direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
dynamicParams.Add("NEWNUMBER", dbType: DbType.String,
    direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 100);
db.Execute("GetNextNumberTest", dynamicParams,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var rval = dynamicParams.Get<int>("rval");
var result = dynamicParams.Get<string>("NEWNUMBER");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your help a lot.